# Gradient sublayer opacity

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote my function to insert a layer (addsubview) to my main view, i gave it vars to manage size and colors for its gradient background with an opacity at 1. I inserted with an index etc...

Now, i would like to manage the opacity of this gradient (background) sublayer through actions :
I'm able to remove it, play with the general opacity of the subview... but impossible to target the opacity of this sublayer at index 0.

Any idea ?

in my viewdidLoad func :

```
func insertHeader () {
    self.view.addSubview(TopMenuView)
    TopMenuView.frame.size.width = self.view.bounds.size.width

    let gradient:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    let colorTop = UIColor(RGBa).cgColor
    let colorBottom = UIColor(RGBa).cgColor
    //etc

    gradient.opacity = 1.0
    TopMenuView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)


}
```

And later, unable to target the opacity of this sublayer gradient...
I can manage the whole opacity of the TopMenuView.layer but not its "background gradient layer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to create a reference to the gradient layer...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var topMenuGradient = CAGradientLayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addSubview(TopMenuView)
        TopMenuView.frame.size.width = self.view.bounds.size.width

        let colorTop = UIColor(RGBa).cgColor
        let colorBottom = UIColor(RGBa).cgColor
        //etc

        topMenuGradient.frame = TopMenuView.bounds

        topMenuGradient.opacity = 0.5

        TopMenuView.layer.insertSublayer(topMenuGradient, at: 0)
    }

    @IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        topMenuGradient.opacity = 0.1
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks you. it works perfect. I don't know why I focused into the viewdidLoad func and forgot the basics : create a reference let...
Nevermind. Thanks for your help.